# R while: mutate only groups in data.frame that do not match condition

Tags: r, while-loop, dplyr

Example data:

```
 df <- data.frame(Date = seq(as.Date("2020-01-01"), by = "day", length.out = 12),
             Phase = c(rep("stable",6),rep("instable",6)),
             n = (c(rep(5,5),4,3,6,6,5,6,5)))
```

I want to return a data.frame with the dates where `n == max(n)` (for each group) but with the condition that each group has to have at least 5 days. If a group has less than 5 days, then the filter should be adjusted to `n == max(n) | n == max(n) - 1` and so on ...

So here is an example:

```
df %>%
  group_by(Phase) %>%
  dplyr::filter(n == max(n)) %>%
  ungroup()

    # A tibble: 8 x 3
  Date       Phase        n
  <date>     <chr>    <dbl>
1 2020-01-01 stable       5
2 2020-01-02 stable       5
3 2020-01-03 stable       5
4 2020-01-04 stable       5
5 2020-01-05 stable       5
6 2020-01-08 instable     6
7 2020-01-09 instable     6
8 2020-01-11 instable     6
```

You can see, that in the first group `stable`(based on the column `Phase`) my target of at least 5 days is met, but not in the second group `instable`

In order to that, I wrote a while loop that lowers the condition in each run until it's met:

```
i <- 0
condition <- FALSE
while(!condition) {
  df_maxdays <- df %>%
    group_by(Phase) %>%
    dplyr::filter(n %in% (max(n, na.rm = T)-i):max(n, na.rm = T)) %>%
    mutate(nn = n()) %>%
    ungroup()
  
  i <- i + 1
  condition <- all(df_maxdays$nn >= 5)
}

df_maxdays
# A tibble: 11 x 4
   Date       Phase        n    nn
   <date>     <chr>    <dbl> <int>
 1 2020-01-01 stable       5     6
 2 2020-01-02 stable       5     6
 3 2020-01-03 stable       5     6
 4 2020-01-04 stable       5     6
 5 2020-01-05 stable       5     6
 6 2020-01-06 stable       4     6
 7 2020-01-08 instable     6     5
 8 2020-01-09 instable     6     5
 9 2020-01-10 instable     5     5
10 2020-01-11 instable     6     5
11 2020-01-12 instable     5     5
```

With my while loop the second group `instable` now contains 5 days which is what I want to have, but the first group now contains also the days where `n >= (max(n)-1)` is true. I would like that on the second run the filter gets adjusted only for the group where the target is not met yet. My required output for that example would be:

```
# A tibble: 11 x 4
       Date       Phase        n    nn
       <date>     <chr>    <dbl> <int>
     1 2020-01-01 stable       5     5
     2 2020-01-02 stable       5     5
     3 2020-01-03 stable       5     5
     4 2020-01-04 stable       5     5
     5 2020-01-05 stable       5     5
     7 2020-01-08 instable     6     5
     8 2020-01-09 instable     6     5
     9 2020-01-10 instable     5     5
    10 2020-01-11 instable     6     5
    11 2020-01-12 instable     5     5
```

Comment: I don't understand your goal. Can you please add the expected final output you are trying to achieve?

Comment: @Edo you are right, it's not that easy to follow along ... I updated my question and hope it's more clear now.

Comment: The logic is still not clear to me. Where did the row with the "2020-01-06" end up?

Comment: In your sample data both phases have 6 days. (See the `rep("instable",6)` in your code.) Could you please update the sample data created by the `df <-` code to match the sample data you show?

Comment: @Edo sorry again, I forgot to update the other part too, now everything should be correct

Comment: @GregorThomas there is no print out of the actual `df`, there is some code before that that applies a filter :-)

Comment: So when you say *"but with the condition that each group has to have at least 5 days"* - that condition is to be checked on the *result* not on the input?

Comment: @GregorThomas exactly. Sorry for the confusion ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood your problem correctly, you just need to use `slice_max`:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
   group_by(Phase) %>% 
   slice_max(n, n = 5) %>% 
   ungroup()
#> # A tibble: 10 x 3
#>    Date       Phase        n
#>    <date>     <chr>    <dbl>
#>  1 2020-01-08 instable     6
#>  2 2020-01-09 instable     6
#>  3 2020-01-11 instable     6
#>  4 2020-01-10 instable     5
#>  5 2020-01-12 instable     5
#>  6 2020-01-01 stable       5
#>  7 2020-01-02 stable       5
#>  8 2020-01-03 stable       5
#>  9 2020-01-04 stable       5
#> 10 2020-01-05 stable       5
```

In this way you always keep at least the 5 highest `n`s within each group.
This is the same result you showed as expected output. The only difference is that `instable` is on top, because of the default reordering of `dplyr`...

Comment: Way to see through the messy problem statement to the underlying goal!

Comment: I can't believe I spent so much time on this when it's actually that easy ... thank you very much. So just to clearify that I get everything correctly. `slice_max` returns all rows where `n == max(n)` but if the result is less than 5 rows it would it returns all rows where `n >= (max(n) -1)`?

Comment: Technically, `slice_max(n,n = 5)` returns the 5 rows that contain the highest value of n. If to get to 5 has to lower the bar  from max(n) to max(n)-1, it just does it.. if you have more than 5 rows with the same value, it keeps them all. Imagine to sort by n and to cut the first 5 rows (or to keep more rows in case of ties).. and that's what `slice_max` does

Comment: @GregorThomas I tried to be as clear as possible, sorry if I failed on that.

Comment: @FelixPhl no worries, sometimes one gets in a trap of thinking about a problem in a certain way that it's very hard to see a simpler way. I was just beginning to understand your view of your problem, but hadn't been able to see through to this simple solution as Edo did so quickly!